# How to test restricted pages? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am having trouble testing if a restricted page is actually doing it's job or not. For example, users need to log in before they can access a page. On this page I have this at the top:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])!="")
{
    header("Location: login.php"); 
}
```

What I believe this should do is make it so that if a user is not logged in, it will redirect them to login.php where they can log in. However, I can't tell if this works or not. When I try to test it in browser, I get access to the page. I don't know if this is because I am still logged in, or if it just doesn't work. How do I properly test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you've started your session, but if not, you need to on **every. single. page.** that requires sessions.

```
session_start();
```

Does the trick.

Your comparison isn't correct. The usual flow is to run an `isset() || empty()` check, instead of checking if `isset()` IS NOT EQUAL TO `""`:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) { ...
```

<sup>*As `isset()` returns a boolean value (`true`/`false`) not a string (`""`)*</sup>

And lastly, your script will continue to be executed, even while redirecting. You need to end the running of your script if the user is not authenticated:

```
session_start(); // start session

if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) || empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    die(header("Location: login.php")); // ends script execution. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, although I get the error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` sometimes

Comment: That error is most likely coming from your `login.php`. What does that code look like?

Comment: @Voken Line 39, where you redirect, might want to end execution there too - `die(header('Location: http://localhost/Boost/Rindex.php'));`.

Comment: Hmm, I still get the error when I type Rindex page directly when I am logged out. Actually, is the `session_start(); // start session

if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']) || empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    die(header("Location: login.php")); // ends script execution. 
}` even necassary ontop of the login page?

Comment: Woah, no you dont want that on the login pages, you only want that on the "access only" pages

Comment: Ok so I will just delete that

Comment: Just put it on the pages that you want to lock down :)